# How to get total Sum of my Collection/Class

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, class, sum

I have this class:

```
public class ExtraDisplayItems
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    public double? ItemSellingPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I then add data to the class with the method below:

```
using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
{
    var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem as ExtraDisplayItems; 

    if (item != null)
    {
        var displayItem = new List<ExtraDisplayItems>
        {
            new ExtraDisplayItems 
            { 
                ItemId = item.ItemId, 
                ItemCode = item.ItemCode, 
                ItemDescription = item.ItemDescription, 
                ItemSellingPrice = item.ItemSellingPrice 
            }
        };
        dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is create a read-only property where I would get the total **Sum** of the `ItemSellingPrice`, but in this property I cannot reach the `Sum` when trying to calculate the `double`?

This is how I wan't the coding to work:

```
public double? SubTotalExtras
{
    get { return ExtraDisplayItems.Sum(x => x.ItemSellingPrice); }
}
```

But... it's giving me the error:

> ExtraDisplayItems does not contain a definition for 'Sum'

How would I go about fixing this?

**EDIT**

I have changed the class to:

```
public class ExtraDisplayItems
{
    private List<ExtraDisplayItems> displayItems;

    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And...

```
        if (item != null)
        {
            this.displayItems = new List<ExtraDisplayItems> //Error
            {
                new ExtraDisplayItems 
                { 
                    ...
                }
            };
            dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

But it now throws the error: *does not contain definition for 'displayItems'*

Comment: @ Patrick Hofmam - Yes I did :)

Comment: `ExtraDisplayItems` is the name of a class. You want `displayItem.Sum(...). (It doesn't help that your names aren't clear - `ExtraDisplayItems` should be singular, and `displayItem` should be plural...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems dat `ExtraDisplayItems` is an instance of the `ExtraDisplayItems` class, which doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` (that is: 'it is a collection of something'). That means that it indeed doesn't have a `Sum` method, nor does the extension method apply.

My best guess at the moment is that you should save the `displayItem` (which is a `List<ExtraDisplayItems>`, so it implements `IEnumerable<ExtraDisplayItems>`) somewhere in your view model and call `Sum` on that.

Also, use naming conventions: you are making plurals singular and the other way around... Very confusing...

Comment: Thank you for the comment sir! How would I be able to do save  `displayItem` to access it somewhere els? 0_o

Comment: Make a class variable.

Comment: It sounds easy enough, but I've never created a class variable and do not know how. I'll go do some research and get back to your main answer when I figure everything out.

Comment: @CareTaker22, yes you did ;) . It is in your code already. Just add `private List<ExtraDisplayItems> displayItems;` to the top of your class. Then change `var displayItem =` to `this.displayItems =`.

Comment: Sorry for all the issues and trouble :( but I have a new problem that I posted in the EDIT of my main question.

Comment: That code should be in the same class as where your method is.

Comment: You've helped me far enough, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Do you know why I might be getting the error:  _Value cannot be null._?

Comment: @CareTaker22 nope, not sure. Is this related to this problem? If not, you'd better ask another question.

Comment: I gave an upvote and gave you the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. Something strange must be going on. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing Linq in your using definitions.

```
using System.Linq;
```

EDIT: 
I was assuming ExtraDisplayItems was a collection, then it is common to have the error 'x does not contain a definition for 'Sum'' even if you see it in code samples.

In order to do the sum various objects you actually need a collection of them not a single object.

Comment: Nope. Asked in comment and OP confirms it is there. It was my first guess to.